# Cannot convert the expression's type 'UIImage?' to type 'Void'

Tags: ios, swift

So I wrote a method that was supposed to take a picture with the camera then return that photo as a `UIImage`. But I've been getting this weird error `Cannot convert the expression's type 'UIImage?' to type 'Void'` and I have no idea what caused it... Here's the code:

> ```
> func captureAndGetImage()->UIImage{
>     dispatch_async(self.sessionQueue, { () -> Void in
>         // Update orientation on the image output connection before capturing
>         self.imageOutput!.connectionWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo).videoOrientation = self.previewLayer!.connection.videoOrientation
>         if let device = self.captureDevice{
>             self.imageOutput!.captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection(self.imageOutput!.connectionWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo), completionHandler: { (imageDataSampleBuffer, error) -> Void in
>                 if ((imageDataSampleBuffer) != nil){
>                     var imageData:NSData = AVCaptureStillImageOutput.jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation(imageDataSampleBuffer)
>                     var image = UIImage(data: imageData)
>                     return image
>                 }
>             })
>         }
>     })
> }
> ```

I've also tried `return image as UIImage` but it didn't work either. 
My guess is that there's something to do with the completion handler.

Thanks!

Comment: I see the problem now.. In the `captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection` call, the return type is `Void`. So how should I change things up so it returns an UIImage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're treating this as a synchronous operation but it is asynchronous. You can't just return the image from an asynchronous operation. You will have to rewrite your method to take a completion block which then gets executed when you retrieve the image. I'd rewrite it to something like the following:

```
func captureAndGetImage(completion: (UIImage?) -> Void) {
    dispatch_async(self.sessionQueue, { () -> Void in
        // Update orientation on the image output connection before capturing
        self.imageOutput!.connectionWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo).videoOrientation = self.previewLayer!.connection.videoOrientation
        if let device = self.captureDevice{
            self.imageOutput!.captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection(self.imageOutput!.connectionWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo), completionHandler: { (imageDataSampleBuffer, error) -> Void in
                var image: UIImage?
                if ((imageDataSampleBuffer) != nil){
                    var imageData:NSData = AVCaptureStillImageOutput.jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation(imageDataSampleBuffer)
                    image = UIImage(data: imageData)
                }
                completion(image)
            })
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: Oh true, I also noted that I forgot the `completionHandler` in `captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection` had a `Void` return type. THanks man I'll go try this out.